# Can I have GCS private isolated buckets with a unique api key per bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I'd like to give to each of my customers access to their own bucket under my GCS enabled app.

I also need to make sure that a user's bucket is safe from other users' actions.

Last but not least, the customer will be a client application, so the whole process needs to be done transparently without asking the user to login.

**If I apply an ACL on each bucket, granting access only to the user I want, can I create an API key only for that bucket and hand that API key to the client app to perform GCS API calls?**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you only have two good options here:

1. Have a service which authenticates the individial app according to whatever scheme you like (some installation license, a random GUID assigned at creation time, whatever) and vends GCS signed URLs, which the end user could then use for a single operation, like uploading an object or listing a bucket's content. The downside here is that all requests must involve your service. All resources would belong entirely to your application.
2. Abandon the "without asking the user to login" requirement and require a single Google login at install time.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Will probably try out the first option.